# Use XML column in where clause in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, xml, oracle, postgresql, hibernate

I want to supporting where clause for columns which containing XML content in `hibernate` for some DBs. I've achived this in `Oracle` by extending `org.hibernate.dialect.OraclexDialect` class and registering xml functions by `registerFunction` method. Example of the generated query:

```
SELECT *
FROM OM_PERSON this_
WHERE xmltype.createxml(this_.config_xml).existsNode('/*[condition/text()="19943"]')=1;
```

The function which is registered in `hibernate` (For `Oracle`):

```
xmltype.createxml(?1).existsNode(?2)
```

Now i want to support `PostgreSQL` (preferred version: **9.6**) too, and i can't find any equivalent function for this. So my question is is there any equivalent function/statement to the above `Oracle` query in `PostgreSQL`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PostgreSQL has a function [`XMLEXISTS`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-xml.html), so your query can looks like:

```
SELECT *
   FROM OM_PERSON x
  WHERE XMLEXISTS('/*[condition/text()="19943"]' PASSING x.config_xml)
```

I have not idea, how it can be used in Hibernate.